# Is CiviCRM compatible with OU Campus (OmniUpdate) CMS

Tags: cms-integration

I have a client currently using civiCRM and Drupal. They are interested in migrating their site content into OU Campus while still maintaining use of CiviCRM. Has anyone had any success with getting these two working. Is it possible?

Thank you,
-n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They can still run CiviCRM on a subdomain separate from the site, likely under Drupal since they already have that installed. See [another answer to a recent question that asked something similar](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/9385/26) about a different system.